# Missing "name" in user profile for some users

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

Given this code:

```
$user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
echo $user_profile['name'];
```

I see the following error for some users:

```
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: name
```

Under what conditions, would the name be missing?

**UPDATE**: Something common with all the users for whom I do not have a name is that their profile "link" does not work. I get a page with the following error msg when I visit them:

```
The page you requested was not found.
You may have clicked an expired link or mistyped the address. Some web addresses are case sensitive.
Return home
Go back to the previous page
```

Bug report for this:
http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/329979473681183

Comment: Probably what you're doing is not returning an array containing the index name, you've got to check the returns of these APIs?

Comment: The array is returned from the facebook-php-sdk and it's not my code.

Comment: Does it missing only name or the response you get is `false`?

Comment: The response array is missing only the name and has the other expected fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out that these were [business accounts](http://www.facebook.com/help/?page=167124440013852) and they don't have names which can be retrieved via the API.

Answer (score 0):

This might be related to these bugs:

http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/297826446918182
http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/320132691332575

Comment: Although the behavior may be the same the bugs are about `friends` connection of `user`, not the user itself...

Comment: Yeah, just put this here since I found it and looking into this further.